# How to get require(packagename) to work, Error: Can't resolve 'api/DefaultApi' in react

Tags: reactjs, require, amd, npm-link

I have a new package to add to my build for a React SPA. I'm using package.json, webpack 3.x and npm. The instructions for the package are:

```
To use the library locally without publishing to a remote npm registry, first install the dependencies by changing 
into the directory containing `package.json` (and this README). Let's call this `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`. Then run:

shell
npm install


Next, [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) it globally in npm with the following, also from `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`:

shell
npm link

Finally, switch to the directory you want to use your nba_v3_headshots from, and run:

shell
npm link /path/to/<JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR>

You should now be able to `require('nba_v3_headshots')` in javascript files from the directory you ran the last 
command above from.
```

When I follow the instructions, I get errors during my production build or development build like this one:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/FooterView/vendor/javascript-client/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ApiClient' in '/Users/{builddir}/app/components/FooterView/vendor/javascript-client/src'
```

In my code I'm loading the package like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
var NbaV3Headshots = require('nba_v3_headshots');
```

In the package's src/index.js
./app/components/FooterView/vendor/javascript-client/src/index.js I have:

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['ApiClient', 'model/Headshot', 'api/DefaultApi'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports, like Node.
    module.exports = factory(require('./ApiClient'), require('./model/Headshot'), require('./api/DefaultApi'));
  }
}(function(ApiClient, Headshot, DefaultApi) {
  'use strict';
var exports = {
    /**
     * The ApiClient constructor.
     * @property {module:ApiClient}
     */
    ApiClient: ApiClient,
    /**
     * The Headshot model constructor.
     * @property {module:model/Headshot}
     */
    Headshot: Headshot,
    /**
     * The DefaultApi service constructor.
     * @property {module:api/DefaultApi}
     */
    DefaultApi: DefaultApi
  };

  return exports;
}));
```

npm ls -g show my package like this:
nba_v3_headshots@1.0.0 -> /Users/{builddir}/app/components/FooterView/vendor/javascript-client

The package is not listed in package.json.

Is there another way to add the package, or to fix the require() ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else hits this, I had to use a regular import statement instead of require.

```
import {ApiClient, Headshot, DefaultApi} from './vendor/javascript-client';
```

I also had to turn off parsing of amd in my config/webpack.config.js like this:

```
const commonRules = [
 {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    parser: {
        amd:false, <---------- here
    },
    query: {
```

because our build has both UMD and AMD imports.